# html_entity_decode not encoding to proper symbol

Tags: php, pdf, decode, html-entities, utf8-decode

Maybe I did not understand everything correctly how htmlentities and decoding of them works.
But I use

```
$text = htmlentities($variable, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML5, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

to save some input into my databse.
Afterwards there is one case where I have to put the content of the database into a pdf.
Whereas my browser reads e.g. a `&comma;` as a ',' or a `&rpar;` as ')'
the Pdf prints exactly `&comma;` or `&rpar;`

I figured out how to search and replace speficic characters with str_replace
but as there is the function html_entitiy_decode I would rather like to use this to display the content.

So I do something like

```
$myContentFromMyDB = html_entity_decode($myContentFromMyDB);
```

But unfortunately I don't see a changing result in my pdf.
Am I mistaken about how the decoding works?
I thought I was right, also having a look at this page:
http://php.net/html_entity_decode

But somehow the conversion does not take place.
I also tried this
    html_entity_decode($myContentFromMyDB, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

but it did not work either.

Any idea?
Is it because I use ISO-8859-1 in the first place?
The thing is that I use code from somebody else and have to work with it. But I don't know whether there is a sense of putting ISO-8859-1 so I don't like the thought of changing it...

Hope somebody can help me with that...

Cheers and thx

Comment: I just found out that the pdf actually displays this correctly:
`$content = htmlentities("we see, because the comma is there");` whereas this `$content = html_entity_decode("we see&comma; because the comma is there");` does not work... how can this be?